# jquery sortable limit amount in a list by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi i want to limit the amount of items in my `<ul id="sortable1">` where the class is equal to 3 items in that list.

I've achieved this when not specific to a class as so:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    //receive: This event is triggered when a
    //connected sortable list has received an item from another list.
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        // so if > 7
        if ($(this).children().length > 7) {
            //ui.sender: will cancel the change.
            //Useful in the 'receive' callback.
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            alert('Your selection has been cancelled. Maximum  7 banners are allowed in the carousel.');

        }
    }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

However when I make this more specific this does not work

```
$('#sortable1').sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",

    revert:true,
    receive: function(event, ui)
    {
        var list = $(this);
            if (list.attr('class') = "defaultbanner") {
                    if (list.children().length > 3) {
                            // move item back to main_list
                                        alert('Only three default banners can be selected!');

                            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                    }
            }
        }
}).disableSelection();
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, can anyone point me into the right direction?

What I want to do is to not allow more than 3 default banners in my `ul` `sortable1`. I've added a class to all my banners called `defaultbanners` to get a handle on this. The way I've implemented above just doesn't work.

Can someone show me how this should be implemented effectively?

My code can be seen on my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm28x/8/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
receive: function(event, ui)
{
    var list = $(this);
    if (list.children('.defaultbanner').length > 3) {
        // move item back to main_list
        alert('Only three default banners can be selected!');
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }
}
```

Example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Sm28x/11/)

Comment: @g_9020 please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question or leave feedback.  Thanks